# Overcoming client isolation for peer to peer audio streaming application

Tags: networking, audio, security, streaming, udp

I am a student developer trying to develop an app that utilizes peer to peer audio streaming with UDP. The app's use case requires it to be used in public settings, specifically places like universities/schools, hotels, auditoriums, theaters, etc.

I am concerned about certain networks with tighter security completely blocking UDP traffic which will essentially make the app cease to function. I have tested the app in some public spaces - specifically a school and hotel. At the school I tested the app at, I spoke with the network administrator and he said that the school network was set up in such a way that it only allowed devices to interact with the router, and not with adjacent devices. (Client isolation.) Because of this, the app cannot establish a peer-to-peer connection to initiate media streaming in the way that I've set it up so far.

The audio data should not leave the network to traverse the open internet, since this will drastically worsen latency and the particular use case for the app requires the audio latency to be <100 ms.

In the past I used the Agora.io framework, which worked on a school network because it streams audio over the internet, but the latency was unacceptable. Then, I opted to use WebRTC instead, which had much better audio latency but didn't function on the school network. Now, I am writing a low-level implementation myself that uses UDP which will most definitely be the fastest, but may not work on public/enterprise networks.

I need to be able to get audio data from point A to point B, which both happen to be on the same network - but client isolation can make this hard. A TURN server could most definitely help me get the IP/Port of another client on the network, but wouldn't client isolation prevent me from communicating with them at all? I have some ideas but I'm not sure which would work / provide good enough results. What is a good course of action here?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

On networks with client isolation, you can't send UDP packets (or anything else) from one client to another without leaving the network. That's the whole point of client isolation.

If latency is a big issue, make sure you have a TURN server or some other relay mechanism close to where your users may be. 100ms is feasible in most cases, as long as you have a server somewhere in the same country. If you're going to have users in multiple countries, add a mechanism to find the nearest server (in terms of latency).